# Convert optional existence to a hashmap to an object oriented design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, data-structures, hashmap

I have a code that has the following structures:

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> shops;  

boolean hasCustomerBeenInShop(int customerId, int shopRefId) {  
   return shops.get("customer_ids").contains(customerId) || shops.get("shop_ids").contains(shopRefId);  
}
```

The hashmap is prepopulated.
I was wondering what would be an effective way to convert this code into a more OO approach?
For example creating an object that has as members the `customerId` and `customerRefId` and overriding the `hash` method would not work since the condition for existence in the map does not depend on both of them being set for the object.
Although the code snippet is simple enough I was wondering if there is a design pattern I am overlooking.

Comment: The real question is: why do you need to save this information in 2 fields? Looking at the name of the method you should just be seeing the `shop_ids` if they have a customerId, why are you seeing the `customer_ids`?

Comment: Because the `shop_ids` do not have the customerIds but have a shop id as a reference that may be optionally set for a customer. Basically conceptually the method returns true if the customerId is part of the customerId collection or the shopRefId is part of the shopIds. I think the argument name caused confusion. I will update post

Comment: If you take `Shop` as a class and  `Map<Id, Customer>` as a variable in that class.In this way you only need to take care of Shop class object and there you can create a method to provide if the customer is in the shop or not